# Vue swap order in slot children's

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

My component take children of slots, and multiply it 'times'. So if get 3 children then it renders 3*3 = 9 elements. If I reverse it before first render then it will render it in reversed order.  But if I will change prop and then return reversed array of component it still renders it the same order.

I try to add key, change key, try to swap vnode.el, but it still keeps order from first rendering.

```js
export default defineComponent({
    name: "cloner",
    props: {
        reverse: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        class: {
            type: String,
        },
        times: {
           type: Number,
           default: 3
        }
         
    },

    computed:{
        items(){
            const defaultSlot = this.$slots.default();
            let clones = [...defaultSlot[0].children];
            for (let i = 0; i < this.scale - 1; i++) {
                const copy = defaultSlot[0].children.map(node => Object.assign({}, node))
                clones = clones.concat(copy);
            }
            defaultSlot[0].children = clones;
            return defaultSlot[0];
        },
        

        children() {
            let items = this.items.children;

            if(this.reves ) {
                return items.reverse()
            }
            return items
        }
    },

    render(){
        return h(
            'li',
            {class: this.class},
            this.children
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: You should try to pass in data into the component instead of slots and then dynamically render the components with `v-for` and `<component :is="">`.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3  I get data from django template MPA. and i get <slider><slider-item/><slider>... so i cant use some of the tolls like v-for or emits. i use provide and vuex to communicate. But i figure out workaround. I use a lot of react and .... vue is not flexlibe like it. not now.

Comment: In Vue, you would normally have static templates which are then converted to JS code while bundling (behind the scene). The static templates then react to your dynamic data and create the relevant DOM elements.

Comment: If you include the compiler it seems to be possible to render a dynamic template: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dynamic-template/20679

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 thanks to point this option. Form you first comment i'don't catch what you mean. But with this helper link now I get it. As i say i figure out nice workaround but in feature i will choose this path. Thanks :)